# Edittext below recyclerview is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am using recyclerview inside nested scrollview. And below recyclerview, I need to place two edittext with button.

But the problem is, Edittext is not focusable (when i place my finger, the red cursor line blinks and hide) and  I couldn't type in the edittext and keyboard also not displaying.

This is my layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Profile icon-->
        <include layout="@layout/common_profile_layout" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:background="@color/colorGrey">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/count_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Ringkasan Aktifitas"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorUserGroup" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dafatar_filter"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_change_day"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="Pilih Tanggal"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:text="06/13/2017"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
        </LinearLayout>



       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite" />


//the below edittext are not working. When i click the edittext, cursor blinks and keyboard is not displaying.

  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/edit_retailer_light_color"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Laporan Via"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sms_rel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sms_icon"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/sms_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sms_icon"
                        android:text="SMS" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edtSms"
                        android:layout_width="222dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                        android:text="sfdsfdfffdssfdfdfsdfds"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sms_text"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border_curve"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rel_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/email_icon"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_mark" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_icon"
                        android:text="Email" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailSms"
                        android:layout_width="222dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_text"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_border_curve" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="148dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/curve_corner"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Kirim"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In code,

i just used only this.

```
public class Activities extends Activity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SummaryAdapter adapter;
    private EditText name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_summary_activities);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    name= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSms);
    adapter = new ActivitiesSummaryAdapter(getData(), this); //list is working fine..
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I couldn't use the edittext. I am clueless what mistake I am doing. Keyboard or focus is not displaying in edittext. Please help me.

Comment: **`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`**

Comment: I used this in manifest. Still not working. @Prem i couldn't click the edittext to bring the keyboard.

Comment: Can you show your *Android Manifest.xml* ?

Comment: i got same problem here, did someone found solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove this line in LinearLayout. This is the one which is blocking the edittext to give input.

**android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"**

Comment: yeah some time if you are added this "projectRecyclerView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);" keyboard won't shows

Answer (score -1):

put one line in your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file . `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"`